# Triple-valued solution to Riemann problem - Profile of the bulge

Tags: characteristics, hyperbolic-equations, cauchy-problem

I am studying conservation laws and hyperbolic systems, particularly, Burgers' equation and shocks, and have a doubt at pages 48/49 of the [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=3WhqLPcMdPsC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) *Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws* by R.J. LeVeque (Birkäuser, 1992).

Sometimes, the characteristics' method give us some triple-valued solution to a question, particularly, a Riemann problem, what seems like a graphic with a bulge, like this

### [image: image of graphic triple-valued]

At page 48, the author says:

> Note that the characteristic velocities are $f'(u)$ so that the profile of this bulge seen here at time $t$ is simply the graph of $tf'(u)$ turned sideways.

I could not understand this. Note that this doubt, if I understood all right, is essencial to use the equal area rule. Is this valid always? Why?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same content is exposed in a section of Ref. (1) on the *Buckley-Leverett equation* as follows (p. 352-353):

> We only need to solve for $q$, the water saturation, and so we can solve a scalar conservation law
>   $$ q_t + f(q)_x = 0 $$
>   with the flux $f(q)$ given by [
>   $$ f(q) = \frac{q^2}{q^2 + a (1-q)^2} . \tag{16.2} $$
>   Here $a<1$ is a constant]. Note that this flux is nonconvex, with a single inflection point.

and

> Now consider the Riemann problem with initial states $q_l = 1$ and $q_r = 0$. By following characteristics, we can construct the triple-valued solution shown in [Fig. 4.7(a) of OP]. Note that the characteristic velocities are $f'(q)$, so that the profile of this bulge, seen here at time $t$, is simply the graph of $t f'(q)$ turned sideways.

Thus, we need to solve a Riemann problem in the [nonconvex case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2539265/418542). We consider a self-similar solution of the form $q(x,t) = v(\xi)$ with $\xi = x/t$. Using the chain rule, we have $q_t = v'(\xi)\xi_t$ and $q_x = v'(\xi)\xi_x$ with $\xi_t = -\xi/t$ and $\xi_x = 1/t$. Injecting the previous Ansatz in the quasi-linear PDE $q_t + f'(q)q_x = 0$ satisfied by the water saturation leads to
$$
\left(f'(v(\xi)) - \xi\right) {v'(\xi)} = 0\, ,
$$
which nontrivial solutions satisfy $f'(q(x,t)) = x/t$. Hence, the bulge at some time $t$ is obtained by plotting $x = t f'(q)$ for $q$ in $[0,1]$. This is illustrated below, where $a=1/2$ and $t=1$ (abscissas $q$, ordinates $x$):

[image: bulge]

It remains to rotate the figure to obtain $q$ as a function of $x$. This topic is also well-explained in an [interactive book](http://www.clawpack.org/riemann_book/index.html), more precisely §1.6 and §5.1 on nonconvex conservation laws.

The equal area rule results from conservation, more precisely from the fact that a discontinuous weak solution must have the same integral as the smooth multivalued solution deduced from the characteristics. This is exactly the way it is applied in Fig. 4.7(b) of OP.

---

[(1)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=QazcnD7GUoUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) R.J. LeVeque, *Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems*, Cambridge University Press, 2002, [doi:10.1017/CBO9780511791253](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511791253)

Comment: Hi, many thanks...! I am studiyng your answer.

Comment: I am afraid that I could not understand very well until now: I am OK until "Injecting this Ansatz...". However, I could not get yet why I can jump from this to "Hence, the bulge at some time...". I could not see the relation between these two phrases... Many thanks.

Comment: I think I am understanding a little bit more, even though I have difficulties. I thank you very much and hope you can continue to follow my questions on modeling math.