# $u_t+u^2u_x=0$ with somewhat arbitrary initial conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I have the following PDE with initial values as stated.
$$u_t+u^2u_x=0\hspace{1 cm} t>0, -\infty<x<\infty$$
$$u(x,t=0)=\begin{cases} 
      -a & x< 0 \\
      0.5 &  x\geq 0 
   \end{cases}$$ where $a>0$.

I know that we can solve this using method of characteristics so we have
$$\frac{dX}{dT}=u^2=\begin{cases} 
      a^2 & x< 0 \\
      0.5^2 &  x\geq 0 
   \end{cases}$$
and from this I know that when $a>0.5$ the characteristic in the middle will be a shock wave with a certain shock speed defining the slope of that shock characteristic. For this, I found $x=\frac{A(u^+)-A(u^-)}{u^{+}-u^-}t=\frac{0.5^2-0.5a+a^2}{3}t$ to be the characteristic line for the shock. I am not sure if this is correct for the characteristic lines in the fan region?

Also, when $a<0.5$ the characteristics between the two sides will be like a fan and we can find the solution for $u(x,t)$ in this fan portion, but I have no idea how I can find a $u(x,t)$ that satisfies this PDE inside of this fan portion of the characteristics. Can someone please help me find this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem at hand is a Riemann problem for the conservation law $u_t+f(u)_x =0$ where the flux function $f:u\mapsto \frac13 u^3$ is non-convex. Here, we have the value $-a<0$ on the left side of the initial discontinuity, and the value $0.5>0$ on the right side. Following [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2539265), the entropy-satisfying solution might be of the following type:

• if $a>1$, then the solution is a shock wave with speed $\frac1{3}(a -\frac12)^2$.

• if $0< a\leq 1$, then the solution is a semi-shock, with intermediate state $u^*=a/2$ satisfying $0< u^*\leq \frac12$.