# Entropy solution for a conservation law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, characteristics

I am trying to find a weak entropy solution for the conservation law

$\partial_tu+\partial_x(u^5)=0 \text{ for } (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)$

$u(x,0)=u_0(x) \text{ for } x\in\mathbb{R}$

where

$u_0(x)= \begin{cases} 
      -1 & x< 0 \\
      0 & x>0
   \end{cases}$

The characteristics $(X,T)$ cross instantaneously at $(0,0)$ which we can remedy by putting a shock $\sigma(t)=t$ there, which satisfies the Rankine-Hugoniot condition. This then gives us

$u(x,t)=\begin{cases} 
      -1 & x<t \\
      0 & x>t
   \end{cases}$

which is a weak solution since it satisfies the conservation law piecewise, and at the discontinuity it satisfies the Rankine-Hugoniot condition. However this is not an entropy solution since there is no constant $C>0$ for which

$u(x+z,t)-u(x,t)\leq C\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)z$

is satisfied for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $z,t>0$. For instance, if we fix $t$ and say that $x<t$, then we can write $t=x+\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Then if we say $z=2\varepsilon$, it follows that $x+z>t$ and

$u(x+z,t)-u(x,z)=0-(-1)=1>C\left(1+\frac{1}{x+\varepsilon}\right)2\varepsilon=C\left(2\varepsilon+\frac{2\varepsilon}{x+\varepsilon}\right)$

for any $C$ if we make $\varepsilon$ small enough (since the right hand side tends to zero).

Of course I will have to try for another weak solution here, but it isn't clear to me what I should do. I have no option but to insert the shock $\sigma(t)$, and after that I feel like it's a guessing game where I put a shock/rarefaction wave/whatever else to make this an entropy solution. Any pointers?

Comment: You should probably make it clear using parenthesis whether you mean $\partial_x(u^5)$ or $(\partial_x u)^5$.

Comment: The problem is that $F(u)=u^5$ isn't convex for $u<0$. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539265/riemann-problem-of-nonconvex-scalar-conservation-laws

Comment: @K.defaoite I've just edited the question (the problem wrote it the way I did but I suspect it meant the former)

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks for linking this, it explains a lot. I haven't studied the Oleinik entropy condition. Judging by the answer, what I have done in my solution (inserting the shock which satisfies Rankine-Hugoniot) is correct, but it still doesn't satisfy the jump condition for an entropy solution. So is it simply not possible in this case (for this initial data) to find an entropy solution?