# Find the entropy solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, characteristics

I want to find the entropy solution of $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)\right)=0$$ with $$u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x<0 \\
1 & \text{ if } x>0 
\end{cases}$$

I found the characteristics , $x=x_0$ if $x_0$ is not zero

Here I got confused what to do. Is the point $(0,0)$ considered a shock point or is there a rarefaction wave solution at it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us rewrite the PDE as follows
$$
u_t + f(u)_x = 0, \qquad f(u) = \sin^2\left(\tfrac{\pi u}2\right) .
$$
Other answers have already shown that base characteristics do not intersect given that
$$
f'(0) = 0 = f'(1), \qquad f'(u) = \tfrac{\pi}{2} \sin (\pi u) .
$$
Since the Rankine-Hugoniot (RH) shock speed is given by $$
s = \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1 - 0} = 1 ,
$$
we conclude that the Lax entropy condition for shock wave solutions is not satisfied. Therefore, it turns out that the shock wave with RH speed $s=1$ is no entropy solution in the usual sense, neither is the static shock solution which contradicts RH.

It should be noted that the function $u \mapsto f(u)$ possesses an inflection point. In other words, the Lax entropy condition is no longer relevant, and we need to look at the Oleinik entropy condition instead (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2539265/418542)). The figure below shows the lower convex hull of the graph of $f$, as described in the solution construction method of the linked post. We find that the entropy solution is a semi-shock, more precisely a rarefaction-shock wave with expression $$
u(x,t) = \begin{cases}
0 , & x \leq 0 \\
\tfrac1\pi \arcsin\left(\tfrac{2}{\pi} \frac{x}{t}\right) , & 0\leq x < s^* t \\
1 , & s^* t < x
\end{cases}
$$
where $u^* \approx 0.258$ satisfies $$
f'(u^*) = \frac{f(1) - f(u^*)}{1 - u^*} = s^* \approx 1.138 .
$$

[image: Semi-shock. Convex hull contruction.]

Answer (score -1):

The essential trick in the method of characteristics is that the solution  $u$ stays (by definition of a characteristic curve) constant along the characteristic curve $x(t)$:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d t} u\big(x(t),t \big) = \partial_t u + \partial_x u \cdot \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} \overset{!}{=} 0 \\
\Rightarrow u\big(x(t), t) = u_0\big(x(t), t\big).$$
By comparing with the PDE
$$u_t + \partial_x f(u) = u_t + f'(u) \cdot u_x =  0$$ you obtain
$$ \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} = f'\Big( u\big(x(t), t\big) \Big) = f'\Big(u_0\big(x(t), t\big) \Big) = f'\Big(u_0\big(x_0(x(t), t)\big)  \Big).$$
In your case:
$$ f'(u_0) = 2 \sin \left( \frac{\pi u_0}2 \right) \cdot \frac \pi2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi u_0}2 \right) = \pi \sin \left( \frac{\pi u_0}2 \right) \cdot \cos \left( \frac{\pi u_0}2 \right).$$
Thus,
$$ \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} = \begin{cases} \pi \sin \left( \frac{\pi \cdot 0}2 \right) \cdot \cos \left( \frac{\pi \cdot 0}2 \right) = \pi \cdot 0 \cdot 1 = 0, & x_0 < 0  \\ \pi \sin \left( \frac{\pi \cdot 1}2 \right) \cdot \cos \left( \frac{\pi \cdot 1}2 \right) = \pi \cdot 1 \cdot 0= 0, & x_0 > 0 .\end{cases}$$
So the characteristic curves are in both cases given by $$x(t) = x_0 , $$ i.e., they do not intersect and the solution reads
$$u(x, t) = u\Big(x_0\big(x(t), t \big) \Big) = u_0(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x< 0 \\ 1, & x > 0. \end{cases} $$

Comment: Why the characteristics are $x=t+x_0$ ? $f'(u_0)=0$ , shouldn't it be $x=0.t+x_0=x_0$ ?